# как правильно настроить FoxyProxy для localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, localhost

Возникла ошибка http://prntscr.com/9m1pwu  которую я не могу решить.
Что я использую сервер - node js
простейший серверок в котором обработчики запросов - мой кусок кода

```
var taskpath = __dirname + '/public/task.json';
app.post('/task',function(req, res){
 var readable = fs.createReadStream(taskpath);
 readable.pipe(res);
});
```

на клиенте  [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)
Пример скрипта:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var t = {};
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:7575/task',
  onload: function(data) {
    var json_text = JSON.stringify(data.response, null, 2),
      your_object = JSON.parse(json_text);

    var href = $('#guide-channels').find('li:contains(' + your_object[0].task[0].channel + ')').find('a').attr('href'),
      videos = 'http://www.youtube.com' + href + '/videos',
      channel = {};
      channel['channel'] = videos;
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
      method: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(channel),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      url: 'http://localhost:8081/getHttp',
      onload: function(xhr) {
        console.log('xhr__', xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
   }
 });
});
```

без прокси все работает, с установкой прокси возникает ошибка.
Я думаю что нужна настройка которой я не знаю. Как подружить прокси и localhost?

Подскажите куда копать

Answer (score 1):

как я понимаю, FoxyProxy, это просто переключалка между прокси серверами. Сам не является прокси-сервером.
Судя по ошибке на скрине запрос идет на localhost:8081 в ожидании прокси-сервера, а он у Вас не установлен, либо порт 8081 закрыт фаерволом.

Comment: как проверить закрыт ли порт 8081 фаерволом? Без прокси все работает отлично!

Comment: как так вы пишите "он у вас не установлен", хотя я его установил прописал ip порт в настройках браузера?

Comment: Вы об этом не упомянули. Если Вы установили прокси-сервер, убедитесь что он запущен и именно на порту 8081. Чтоб ответить по фаерволу нужно знать как минимум Вашу ОС. Дате больше информации

Comment: window 10 браузер firefox

Comment: @little_boy [отключите](http://windows.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-10/turn-windows-firewall-on-or-off) фаервол для проверки. То что прокси запущен проверили?

Comment: не не помогло.( Я использую node js запускаю файл app.js на порту например 8081 app.js обрабатывает запросы и отсылает данные на клиент. Прокси у меня такой как щас стоит 51.254.205.35:3128

Comment: @little_boy бррр.. с этого надо было начинать. Если у Вас уже в настройках стоит какойто прокси, то конечно он не может подключиться к localhost:8081

Comment: И че можно сделать?

Comment: а что хотите сделать? уберите прокси 51.254.205.35 и подключайтесь напрямую к localhost:8081. Если хотите чтоб ваше арр работало через прокси в интернете надо указывать не localhost, а ваш внешний ip адрес, возможно пробрасывать порт если используете роутер и т.д. и т.п

Comment: Где мне указать внешний ip. В каком месте? Мне надо чтоб конкретно работало через прокси в интернете. Как мне лучше сделать?

Comment: в ошибке на скрине идет запрос на localhost:8081. Кто делает этот запрос не понятно, что это за localhost не понятно, как устроена сеть не понятно. Ответить на вопрос невозможно. Опишите все и тогда возможно будет ответить. Если Вы хотите чтоб арр работал через интернет не размещайте его у себя на компе, а разместите в интернете на хостинге.